# UICollectionView | Cell reusable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, prepareforreuse

SO, `UICollectionView` is being a real pain for me right now. Consider I have a `UIViewController` which has a `UICollectionView` embedded in it. Well each cell of the CollectionView is almost the entire width of the `UIViewController`. And each cell contains some buttons and images. When I select one button and tend to make the button retain its state, the CollectionView reuses the cell and kind of duplicates the cell states across other cells as well. However when I try to put the cells in an array and kind of want to check the states of cells in that array, the `cellForItemAt` method overwrites those cells. I am so confused. Please help. Even `prepareForReuse` in `UICollectionViewCell` isn't helping. Here is some code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddressCollectionViewCell
    cell.shopAddressDetailLbl.text = ""
    cell.addressObj = addresses[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCellForAddress(cell.addressObj)
    cell.cellTag = indexPath.row
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    if addressCells.contains(cell) == false {
        addressCells.append(cell)
    } else {
        if cell.isAddressConfirmed == true {
            cell.confirmAddress.setTitle("CONFIRMED", for: .normal)
            cell.confirmAddress.isEnabled = false
            cell.confirmAddress.backgroundColor
                = UIColor(red: 0, green: 100/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            addressCells[indexPath.row] = cell
        }
    }
    return cell
}

extension AddressesCollectionViewController: AddressCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func confirmBtnPressed(confirmAddressObj: Address, cell:AddressCollectionViewCell) {
        for cellTemp in addressCells {
            if cellTemp == cell && cellTemp.isAddressConfirmed == false {
                if let dele = addressCollectionViewDelegate {
                    cellTemp.isAddressConfirmed = true
                    dele.configureCellsAccordingToChanges(cell: cellTemp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    cellTag = 0
    confirmAddress.setTitle("Confirm Address", for: .normal)
    confirmAddress.backgroundColor = APP_UNIVERSAL_COLOR
    confirmAddress.isEnabled = true
}
```

Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: you are appending array in cellForItemAt while what you need is append array in button action.

Comment: also appending whole cell in array and then checking  cell exist will not give you correct result as some buttons images are changed some buttons may be enabled and some disabled even some cell can match even they were not appended in array so i think appending in cellForItem is a bad idea.

Comment: I understand what you're suggesting here but I can't seem to find a way around it.

Comment: append address cell under any user action brother

Comment: Thank you but how will appending them there will help my cause?

Comment: **Never ever** use an array to save cells temporarily. Don't. The main issue is that you have to save the value of `isAddressConfirmed` in your data model so it's updated correctly when `cellForItem` is called. And you are misusing `prepareForReuse()`. Add an `else` branch in `cellForItem` to set the UI elements to the default states.

Comment: appending will help as you are in need to just save the address button state so you may save it in array in form of true and false, and check on cellForItem if state is active show active state UI and  in else show disabled state UI :)

Comment: I think I am there now :) Well to be honest there was need to append any cells at all or to poll them. Thank you guys! You're the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vadian, @Abu Ul Hassan

Pretty slick! To others who need help in this regard. Vadian suggested in comments that I just need to update and monitor my model and thats exactly what I did. SO here it goes:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddressCollectionViewCell
    cell.shopAddressDetailLbl.text = ""
    cell.addressObj = addresses[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCellForAddress(cell.addressObj)
    cell.cellTag = indexPath.row
    cell.cellDelegate = self

    if addresses[indexPath.row].isConfirmed! == true {
        cell.confirmAddress.setTitle("CONFIRMED", for: .normal)
        cell.confirmAddress.isEnabled = false
        cell.confirmAddress.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 100/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    } else {
        cell.confirmAddress.setTitle("Confirm Address", for: .normal)
        cell.confirmAddress.isEnabled = true
        cell.confirmAddress.backgroundColor = APP_UNIVERSAL_COLOR
    }
    return cell
}

extension AddressesCollectionViewController: AddressCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func confirmBtnPressed(confirmAddressObj: Address, cell:AddressCollectionViewCell) {
        if confirmAddressObj.isConfirmed! == false {
            if let dele = addressCollectionViewDelegate {
                cell.isAddressConfirmed = true
                dele.configureCellsAccordingToChanges(cell: cell)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And its ALIVE :D